# Handle long fireAllRules in Drools

Tags: java, out-of-memory, drools

I currently ran into a problem in our Drools server.

We receive pretty large requests to our drools server farm that throws an `OutOfMemoryError`. Those large request shouldn't be process (they are bugs), and if a request takes more than 5s it should be canceled.

I've trying to workaround this with a custom *timeout* DRL rule [has explained here](https://blog.vizuri.com/how-to-detect-an-infinite-loop-in-your-brms-rules-and-auto-recover-part3):

```java
    rule "Stop the rule engine after 5s"
        timer ( int: 5s )
        salience 0
    when
    then
        System.err.println("*** Stop the rule engine after 5s ***");
        drools.halt();
    end
```

But this rule is never taking into account.
So I've tried another workaround: put my `ksession.fireAllRules();`in a thread, and if it takes more tahn 5 second, halt drools with `ksession.halt();`; like this:

```java
    KieSessionConfiguration conf = kieServices.newKieSessionConfiguration();
    final KieSession ksession = kcontainer.newKieSession(conf);

    Thread droolsThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            ksession.fireAllRules();                        
        }
    }, "drools");

    long tStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
    droolsThread.start();

    /*wait until the end of the Thread or 5 seconds max*/
    while (System.currentTimeMillis() - tStart < 5000 && droolsThread.isAlive())
        Thread.sleep(100);

    /*if alive for more than 5 seconds stop it*/
    if (droolsThread.isAlive())
    {
        System.err.println("timeout killing drools");
        ksession.halt();
        ksession.dispose();
    }
```

In this second scenario, when drools is called with the `ksession.fireAllRules();`, it starts executing the request, and if this a huge one throws the `Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` exception:

```
[apache-tomcat-9.0.39]: timeout killing drools
[apache-tomcat-9.0.39]:  Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "Catalina-utility-1"
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

I don't know what to do to stop those large request eating all the server memory.
Is it possible to stop a long request currently running in drools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were on the right track, but you need to start the rule execution using *fireUntilHalt* (instead of fireAllRules):
https://docs.drools.org/7.40.0.Final/kie-api-javadoc/org/kie/api/runtime/rule/StatefulRuleSession.html#fireUntilHalt--

Then you will be able to stop it via *halt* method.

I would also advise into looking why you are seeing this pattern of "eating all the server memory". Maybe there will be opportunity to optimize your rules..

Comment: Thank Anton for you answer! I'll update my code an make test. BTW we implement drools on a Tomcat server as a `public class KnowledgeStatelessServlet extends HttpServlet` (AKA an API). I'm afraid that if I use `fireUntilHalt` my POST requests will be running forever...

Comment: In that case, I would advise into trying to understand why you are seeing that behaviour in the first place. You said those requests are bugs and shouldn't be processed - can't you then filter out, and simply NOT insert into kie session?

Comment: You're right. I'll try your solution and @Dr Dave one, since I can easily reproduce the problem.

Comment: fireAllRules(limit) can lead to losing valuable results - because you are preventing Drools to process all the matches, and limit it to execute only N (==limit) matches. Hard to know whether it can be useful to your use case, but I simply advise being careful - it can give you illusion of fixing the bug, but can produce undesired side effect and result in data loss.

Comment: I know this is an old thread, but in the OP's code snippet, it doesn't appear that ksession.dispose() gets called when the drools thread executes on time.

Comment: It's a nice safety net and I just moved ksession.dispose(); outside the 'if' condition.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following API on a StatefulRuleSession:

fireAllRules(int max)
Fire Matches on the Agenda up to the given maximum number of Matches, before returning the control to the application.

On consuming memory, you could profile the memory usage (at the Java level)  to see what is going on.  Rule-based applications generally use a lot of memory from making a memory-processing time trade-off using algorithms derived from RETE